# Why is my Retrofit2 get request not working?

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

I´m trying to get json from site with Retrofit2. When I´m debugging the app doesn´t continue on this line:  `Call<List<PostJson>> call = service.get_json("54");`

I don´t know what to do...I´m begginer at android and I tried a lot of tutorials and none works for me.

Can someone help me with it, please?

MainAcitvity:

```
 final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl("http://matej.martintoth.sk/")
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();

JsonGet service = retrofit.create(JsonGet.class);

                        Call<List<PostJson>> call = service.get_json("54");
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PostJson>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<List<PostJson>> call, Response<List<PostJson>> response) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("OK"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                List<PostJson> allRepos = response.body();                        
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<List<PostJson>> call, Throwable t) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("KO"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

PostJson.java:

```
package appka.matej.lukas.pizzerias;

public class PostJson {

        final String name;

        public PostJson(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
}
```

JsonGet.java (interface):

```
package appka.matej.lukas.pizzerias;

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface JsonGet {

    @GET("api/pizzerias.php?date={user}")

    Call<List<PostJson>> get_json(@Path("user") String user);

}
```

Comment: put log in onresponse and check whether you are getting response In log or not...

Comment: did you use jsontopojo tool to convert your json response ?